# CKEditor - change all content

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to make an option that after clicking CKEditors button (like 'bold', 'justify', 'font-size', etc.) change all text not only selected part (something like autoselection).

I have code:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace( "textEditor",{
    on : {
        'beforeCommandExec' : function(ev){
            var sel = ev.editor.getSelection();
            var element = sel.getStartElement();
            sel.selectElement(element);
        }
     }
});
```

it makes selection but don't change content.

Answer (score 0):

I changed code to:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace( "textEditor",{
    'beforeCommandExec' : function(ev){
       var sel = ev.editor.getSelection();
       var element = sel.getStartElement();
       sel.selectElement(element);
    }
 }
```

});

and it's working, but only when editor on start is empty. If is any text onload, and i click b, u, i buttons i get error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getParent' of null
```